# Magento2: Product backend page error

Tags: magento2, product, extensions

I uninstalled MageWorx SEO extension and I am experiencing the following error.

```
Class MageWorx\SeoBase\Model\Source\CrossDomainStore does not exist
```

Checking the error report, I get this

```
{"0":"Class MageWorx\\SeoBase\\Model\\Source\\CrossDomainStore does not exist",
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you checked the class letters with folder name?...it is case sensitive

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by dropping the `cross domain store` attribute from the `eav_attribute` table.

Answer (score 1):

Goto table **eav_attribute** and search for **backend_model**, **frontend_model** and **source_model**
**MageWorx\SeoBase\Model\Source\CrossDomainStore** like below:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `backend_model` LIKE '%MageWorx\SeoBase\Model\Source\CrossDomainStore%';
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `frontend_model` LIKE '%MageWorx\SeoBase\Model\Source\CrossDomainStore%';
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `source_model` LIKE '%MageWorx\SeoBase\Model\Source\CrossDomainStore%';
```

And delete those attributes if those are not magento's default attribute or place NULL instead of **MageWorx\SeoBase\Model\Source\CrossDomainStore**

Run di:compile and other required commands then test.